# Submit form button not working laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I have two scenarios where a user is required to update the record on the `calls` database. One is when the `call` is to be assigned to an engineer (this I have successfully implemented). The second is when a `call` is to be closed. I have two controllers; one handling the first process and the second `closeCallsController` handling this second process.

Am trying to update a record in the `calls` database with **this form**

```
<form action="{{route('Call.update', $calls->id)}}" method="POST">

    @csrf
    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="terminal_id">{{ __('Terminal ID') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="terminal_id" id="terminal_id" class="form-control" value="{{$calls->terminal_id}}" style="padding: 20px;" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="terminal_name">{{ __('Terminal name') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="terminal_name" id="terminal_name" class="form-control" value="{{$calls->terminal_name}}" style="padding: 20px;" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="closed_on">{{ __('Date and time of closure') }}</label><br>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="closed_on" id="closed_on" class="form-control" style="padding: 20px;" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group col-xs-6 form-group">
        <label for="operations_comment">{{ __('Comment') }}</label><br>
        <textarea name="operations_comment" id="operations_comment" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="20"  required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; border: 0;">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
</form>
```

But when I click on the `Submit` button, it simply reloads the page without updating the database nor redirecting to the `closedCalls` page.

**here is my `closeCallsContoller`**

```
public function edit($id)
{
$calls = Call::find($id);
return view('pages.closeCall')->with('calls', $calls);
}

/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
//validate
$this->validate($request,[
'terminal_id' => 'required',
'terminal_name' => 'required',
'pending_on' => 'required',
'closed_on' => 'required',
'operations_comment' => 'required'
]);


//store in the database
$call = Call::find($id);
$call->terminal_id = $request->input('terminal_id');
$call->terminal_name = $request->input('terminal_name');
$call->closed_on = $request->input('closed_on');
$call->operations_comment = $request->input('operations_comment');
$call->call_status = 'Closed';
$call->pending_on = 'Closed';
$call->closed_by = Auth::user()->name;
$call->save();

return redirect('/pages/closedCalls');
}
```

**And this is my route**

```
Route::get('/pages/closeCall/{id}', 'CloseCallsController@edit');
Route::resource('CloseCalls', 'CloseCallsController');
```

**This is my `Call` model**

```
class Call extends Model{

protected $fillable = [
'terminal_id',
'terminal_name',
'call_status',
'pending_on',
'closed_on',
'operations_comment',
'closed_by'
];

//describing a one-to-many-relationship between calls and users
public function user(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: try to inspect element your form check the action attribute that might blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any route named Call route which you give in the update form action.

Try with this

```
<form action="{{route('CloseCalls.update', $calls->id)}}" method="POST"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated my route just like @Jasim rightly said but the form still didn't submit. After some tests, I discovered that the code breaks during validation so, I added

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Immediately before `@csrf` in order to display the errors, then I found out that the field `pending_on` was not included on the form, but it was set to `required` on the validation check. so, I simply deleted it and the code works...thanks guys